# UTF-8 Corrupted from MySQL to SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, utf-8

I'm porting a PHP Web application I wrote from MySQL 5 to SQLite 3. The text encoding for both is UTF-8 (for all fields, tables, and databases). I'm having trouble transferring a geo database with special characters.

`mb_detect_encoding()` detects both as returning UTF-8 data.

For example,

**Raw output:**

MySQL (correct): Dārāb, Iran
SQLite (incorrect): DÄrÄb, Iran

**JSON-encoded:**

MySQL (correct): D\u0101r\u0101b, Iran
SQLite (incorrect): D\u00c4\u0081r\u00c4\u0081b, Iran

**What fixes the problem:**

```
$sqlite_output = utf8_encode($sqlite_output);
$sqlite_output = utf8_decode($sqlite_output);
```

I imagine there's a way of repairing the SQLite database. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you using to transfer the data? At which point does the problem pop up?  What character set and collation are used exactly on the mySQL, and the SQLite side?

Comment: I used `mysqldump` to `sqlite3 .read` after cleaning up the statements for compatibility but not touching the data. MySQL is `utf8_general_ci` and SQLite `PRAGMA encoding;` returns `UTF-8`. It crops up using PHP::PDO.

Comment: Does a `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tablename` in MySQL also show the table itself is of the right charset? It is possible to ram utf-8 in other types of charset columns, and with the proper chain of events it can take a while before you notice.

Comment: If you used a not-so-clever editor to clean up the statements, are you sure it didn't save the file as ISO-8859 or such?

Comment: Yes, the MySQL table reports as UTF8. I used TextMate (Mac) to make the changes, and it's UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks for the advice and comments. Unfortunately, no matter which configurations I chose, it wouldn't take. I ended up simply initiating two PDO objects and, using a `while` loop, inserting one row at a time. (I used `mysqldump`'s `--no-data` option to get the structure and modified that by hand.)

It took about 10 minutes to insert ~10,000 rows equal to 9.4MB of data on my 256MB CentOS box. (So if you're on a shared environment, be wary of the maximum execution time.) The SQLite database now returns proper Unicode data.

Note to self: It's easier to code a work-around than finding the recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to transfer the data again from MySQL to SQLite. I don't think you can predictably revert back to proper encoding, as it seems SQLite interpreted utf8-input as non-utf8 or visa versa when the data first arrived, therefore not storing it in a proper format.

So try to transfer again, while making sure the whole chain of data between MySQL to SQLite is aware of the utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The default PHP distribution builds libsqlite in ISO-8859-1 encoding mode. However, this is a misnomer; rather than handling ISO-8859-1, it operates according to your current locale settings for string comparisons and sort ordering. So, rather than ISO-8859-1, you should think of it as being '8-bit' instead.